# Using a variable in a python postgres SQL statement

Tags: python, postgresql, variables

I'm trying to use a variable in a SQL statement however it comes up with the error:

TypeError: function takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)

To be honest, I'm no master programmer and have little experience with postgres so it's probably quite an easy solution.

Also, if there is another way of doing this that would be very helpful.

Thanks for any help

```
 conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=postgres user=postgres password=postgres")

 cur = conn.cursor()

 cur.execute("SELECT password FROM user WHERE email = ",inputed_email,";")
 print(cur.fetchone())
        
 cur.close()
 conn.close()
```

## inputed_email is a variable that matches one of the records in the user table

Comment: This is the worst piece of code, it's prone to SQL injection. Never ever write SQL as if it's just a piece of text. It's SQL, used to interact with your database. Use placeholders for (user) input: https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/basic/params.html

Comment: @FrankHeikens, the OP is using `psycopg2` not `psycopg(3)`. While the process is roughly the same it is not exactly the same per [Server Binding](https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/basic/from_pg2.html#server-side-binding). The better link would be https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cur.execute("SELECT password FROM user WHERE email = ",inputed_email,";")
```

This line of code is wrong for two reasons.

First, as the error says, the `execute()` function takes at most two arguments, but you passed three.  You can't just add extra stuff at the end, like you would when you use `print()`.

Second, if you want to execute an SQL statement that contains a variable, there is a different way to do that, using *placeholders*.

Anywhere you want to use a variable in the statement, use `%s` as a placeholder instead:

```
SELECT password FROM user WHERE email = %s
```

(I don't know if the `;` at the end is needed.  If it is, just add it.)

And then the second argument to `execute()` is a list (or a tuple) of all the values that you want to substitute into the query:

```
cur.execute("SELECT password FROM user WHERE email = %s", [inputed_email])
```

In this case there is only one value you want to substitute, but the second argument still must be a list, so it's a list of one item.

If you wanted to execute a query that uses more than one placeholder, it might look like this:

```
cur.execute("SELECT password FROM user WHERE email = %s and lastname = %s", [email, lastname])
```

Comment: Note that the [Python DBAPI specification](https://peps.python.org/pep-0249/) allows for a [variety of syntaxes for parameterized queries](https://peps.python.org/pep-0249/#paramstyle); consult your library's documentation to see what it supports if `%s` does not work.